# RabbitMQ disable authentication

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to run RabbitMQ server with no Authentication/Authorization backend for DEV environment?

I have tried to configure the `auth_backends` with empty list like:

`{auth_backends, []},`

But it just deny all connections.

Answer (score -4):

Why would you want to do that in first place?

You can configure just a username and password, with AMQPLAIN as the authentication method, that should be fairly convenient for development.

Comment: If I'm using a password I need to store it in a safe location and this process is very tedious, on all other services (like MySQL, Elastic...) this is possible to just disable the authentication.

Comment: There are scenarios where this is a valid case and makes perfect sense, i.e. if you have other means of authentication and authorization, or if you have restricted access (like a local test environment)

Comment: @AmirRossert Your argument does not make sense. If you are only in a dev environment, why would you have to store the password in a safe location? Why not use username=test and password=test ?

Comment: Also, some rabbitmq instances might be purposefully available for anyone to access them. Some use cases might need this. And this post does not answer the question.